# Blogger published-max not working?

Tags: blogger

I have a problem with Blogger and the published-max parameter. It's always giving me the complete list of posts, not up-to and until the passed date.

Either I'm overlooking something obvious for the last hour or I'm doing it the wrong way ...

Here's an example link : https://macvos.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/full?q=label%3Abooks&published-max=2016-04-17T23%3A59%3A00&orderby=published

The first post listed is from 30-10-2017 ... not 04-2016.

Any ideas much appreciated!

**UPDATE**:

Found the answer here : https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#Queries